# Apply shift for comparison on multiple columns over groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a dataframe(raw_data) containing multiple columns:

```
raw_data = {'one': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B'],'two' : [3,4,5,6,2,7,9,12,1,10,11,8],'three': ['bcd','qpv', 'cba','klm','zfv','klm','abc','abc','abc','lmf','fly','zdb'],'four':['cba','klm','tcf','fly','zfb','zdb','pcd','tlm','bcd','klm','mvt','jbm'], 'five':['apple','lemon','banana','water','kiwi','lemon','orange','apple','apple','straw','water','pom']}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['one', 'two', 'three','four','five'])
```

From this df, I can generate new columns or directly shift by 1 for column three & five.

Output:

1) Groupby 'one'

2) sort by 'two'

3) shift 'three' 1 level up, new column 'three_new'

4) shift 'five' 1 level, new column 'five_new'

5) compare 'four' with 'three_new' & 'five' with 'five_new', if both match 
remove the first row & continue

6) comparison on groupby

The output looks like this :

```
one two three   four    five
A   3   bcd     cba     apple
A   5   cba     tcf     banana
A   9   abc     pcd     orange
B   2   zfv     zfb     kiwi
B   7   klm     zdb     lemon
B   8   zdb     jbm     pom
B   10  lmf     klm     straw
C   11  fly     mvt     water
C   12  abc     tlm     apple
```

Initial df has 12 rows & output df has 9 rows, filtered on the above criteria. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: I'm not sure on how to use lambda with assignment over groupby. can you suggest a reasonable solution for this ? I'm trying to solve it without defining a function

Comment: I hope it's making sense now #Boud.